# How can I change inline forms in django admin?

Tags: python, django

In my django projects I have 2 related models "Vehicle"(parent model) and ParamConf(child model). ParamConf has field "program" and I want to fix some wrong values in it.
(admin.py):

```
class ParamConfFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(ParamConfFormSet, self).clean()

        for form in self.forms:
            if hasattr(form, 'cleaned_data') and 'program' in form.cleaned_data:

                program = form.cleaned_data['program'].lower() # <<< I want to save this changed value
                form.cleaned_data['program'] = program # <<< but this doesn't work :^(

class ParamConfInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.ParamConf
    formset = ParamConfFormSet


class VehicleAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Vehicle

class VehicleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ ParamConfInline, ]
    form = VehicleAdminForm
```

I even wrote save() method for ParamConf, but django doesn't want to call it after saving a  Vehicle form(Vehicle's save method is alright).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Django emits save signals for inline parameters if field values actually changed (and I was trying to save form without editing fields). Sorry it's my fault.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is very old, but someone else may be still looking for the answer...Saving a inline even if it was not changed:

```
Class EntityInline(admin.TabularInline):
    extra = 0
    model = Entity
    form = AlwaysChangedModelForm
```